# How to implement a generic OpenForm method to allow any type of Form

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code in `FormMain : Form`
How to implement the `OpenForm` method to allow me open any type of `Form`?

```
    // the method in question
    void OpenFrom<T>()
    {
        // How to implement this generic method to get rid of OpenForm1() and OpenForm2() ???
    }

    // Open Form1 instance
    void OpenForm1()
    {
        new Form1().Show();
    }

    // Open Form2 instance
    void OpenForm2()
    {
        new Form2().Show();
    }

    OpenForm<Form1>(); // instead of OpenForm1()
    OpenForm<Form2>(); // instead of OpenForm2()
```

Comment: This looks like the wrong approach and an abuse of generics to me - I would rather have a method with the signature `OpenForm(Form form)` and instantiate the `Form` outside of the `OpenForm` method (or at least pass in a factory).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how you go

```
 void OpenFrom<T>() where T : Form, new()
 {
     new T().Show();
 }
```

Comment: are these windows forms? If they are you would be creating new instances of that form and not using the preexisting ones, correct?

Comment: @hunter, well that appears to be the intent in OP's code

Comment: @hunter I believe that's what question is all about.

Comment: While this answer technically answers the question, I get the feeling that using generics at all in this instance is just an ugly patch to a poor approach to the problem.

Comment: Thank you Sriram for your answer, another thing I have a method Form GetMdiChildForm(Type t), How would I call it inside OpenForm<T>()?

Comment: @Jalil If I understand correctly then you need this `GetMdiChildForm(typeof(T))`. btw this method looks odd for me, Can't guess what it is doing with `Type` argument?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It returns the current opened instance of the MdiChild form of type t, what do you think?

Comment: @Jalil Fine, Just asked out of curiosity. If that makes sense for you go for it :)